# Java 7 vs Java 8 HashMap resizing

Tags: java, hashmap

In Java 7, HashMap resize() created a temporary newTable, transferred the contents into it and then assigned the temporary newTable to the original table.

```
void resize(int newCapacity) {
    Entry[] oldTable = table;
    int oldCapacity = oldTable.length;
    if (oldCapacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
        threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        return;
    }

    Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
    boolean oldAltHashing = useAltHashing;
    useAltHashing |= sun.misc.VM.isBooted() &&
            (newCapacity >= Holder.ALTERNATIVE_HASHING_THRESHOLD);
    boolean rehash = oldAltHashing ^ useAltHashing;
    transfer(newTable, rehash);
    table = newTable;
    threshold = (int)Math.min(newCapacity * loadFactor, MAXIMUM_CAPACITY + 1);
}
```

In Java 8, while HashMap resize() still creates a temporary newTab, but the assignment is made before the contents are changed.

```
final Node<K,V>[] resize() {
    Node<K,V>[] oldTab = table;
    int oldCap = (oldTab == null) ? 0 : oldTab.length;
    int oldThr = threshold;
    int newCap, newThr = 0;
    if (oldCap > 0) {
        if (oldCap >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            return oldTab;
        }
        else if ((newCap = oldCap << 1) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY &&
                 oldCap >= DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY)
            newThr = oldThr << 1; // double threshold
    }
    else if (oldThr > 0) // initial capacity was placed in threshold
        newCap = oldThr;
    else {               // zero initial threshold signifies using defaults
        newCap = DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        newThr = (int)(DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR * DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }
    if (newThr == 0) {
        float ft = (float)newCap * loadFactor;
        newThr = (newCap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY ?
                  (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    threshold = newThr;
    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
        Node<K,V>[] newTab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[newCap];
    table = newTab;
    if (oldTab != null) {
        for (int j = 0; j < oldCap; ++j) {
            Node<K,V> e;
            if ((e = oldTab[j]) != null) {
                oldTab[j] = null;
                if (e.next == null)
                    newTab[e.hash & (newCap - 1)] = e;
                else if (e instanceof TreeNode)
                    ((TreeNode<K,V>)e).split(this, newTab, j, oldCap);
                else { // preserve order
                    Node<K,V> loHead = null, loTail = null;
                    Node<K,V> hiHead = null, hiTail = null;
                    Node<K,V> next;
                    do {
                        next = e.next;
                        if ((e.hash & oldCap) == 0) {
                            if (loTail == null)
                                loHead = e;
                            else
                                loTail.next = e;
                            loTail = e;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (hiTail == null)
                                hiHead = e;
                            else
                                hiTail.next = e;
                            hiTail = e;
                        }
                    } while ((e = next) != null);
                    if (loTail != null) {
                        loTail.next = null;
                        newTab[j] = loHead;
                    }
                    if (hiTail != null) {
                        hiTail.next = null;
                        newTab[j + oldCap] = hiHead;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newTab;
}
```

While HashMap is never thread-safe, the "size" and actual size in "table" were always same during resizing (in Java 7), which it no longer is.  Any specific reason why Java did this, instead of doing

```
    table = newTab;
```

right at the end, after transferring the contents into newTab?

Comment: How can the chances of `ConcurrentModificationException` be higher if it's not accessed by multiple threads?

Comment: Maybe someone thought, as long as we're not writing a thread-safe class, we shouldn't be going through the motions of thread-safety.

Comment: Apologies - you are right.  It doesn't increase the chances of ConcurrentModException as modCount remains the same, but if you look at writeObject, it writes a different "size" compared the actual keys/values, which it wouldn't if we had done "table = newTab" at the end.

Comment: I am not arguing it is wrong, I am just trying to find out if there was reason to assigning this (prior to transferring the contents).

Comment: Why does it matter? Every implementation and every version can do it differently, as long as they adhere to the contract (API) as defined by the javadoc.

Comment: Probably no particular reason, but as you can see, the method was totally re-implemented, because of the [new improved collision handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html). When you re-write code, it ends up being different. Whether assigning field first or last makes no difference to the defined functionality of the method, so why would a re-write strive to that particular part of the entire operation in the exact same way?