# java 7 vs java 8 hashmap (de)serialization

Tags: java, serialization, hashmap

In Java 7, the writeObject was fail-fast in that it used an iterator (foreach).

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
    throws IOException
{
    Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> i =
        (size > 0) ? entrySet0().iterator() : null;

    // Write out the threshold, loadfactor, and any hidden stuff
    s.defaultWriteObject();

    // Write out number of buckets
    s.writeInt(table.length);

    // Write out size (number of Mappings)
    s.writeInt(size);

    // Write out keys and values (alternating)
    if (size > 0) {
        for(Map.Entry<K,V> e : entrySet0()) {
            s.writeObject(e.getKey());
            s.writeObject(e.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

In Java 8, the writeObject uses a simple for loop and is no longer fail-fast.

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s)
    throws IOException {
    int buckets = capacity();
    // Write out the threshold, loadfactor, and any hidden stuff
    s.defaultWriteObject();
    s.writeInt(buckets);
    s.writeInt(size);
    internalWriteEntries(s);
}

// Called only from writeObject, to ensure compatible ordering.
void internalWriteEntries(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
    Node<K,V>[] tab;
    if (size > 0 && (tab = table) != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
            for (Node<K,V> e = tab[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
                s.writeObject(e.key);
                s.writeObject(e.value);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream s)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Read in the threshold (ignored), loadfactor, and any hidden stuff
    s.defaultReadObject();
    reinitialize();
    if (loadFactor <= 0 || Float.isNaN(loadFactor))
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Illegal load factor: " +
                                         loadFactor);
    s.readInt();                // Read and ignore number of buckets
    int mappings = s.readInt(); // Read number of mappings (size)
    if (mappings < 0)
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Illegal mappings count: " +
                                         mappings);
    else if (mappings > 0) { // (if zero, use defaults)
        // Size the table using given load factor only if within
        // range of 0.25...4.0
        float lf = Math.min(Math.max(0.25f, loadFactor), 4.0f);
        float fc = (float)mappings / lf + 1.0f;
        int cap = ((fc < DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY) ?
                   DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY :
                   (fc >= MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
                   MAXIMUM_CAPACITY :
                   tableSizeFor((int)fc));
        float ft = (float)cap * lf;
        threshold = ((cap < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY && ft < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
                     (int)ft : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes","unchecked"})
            Node<K,V>[] tab = (Node<K,V>[])new Node[cap];
        table = tab;

        // Read the keys and values, and put the mappings in the HashMap
        for (int i = 0; i < mappings; i++) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                K key = (K) s.readObject();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                V value = (V) s.readObject();
            putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, false);
        }
    }
}
```

In Java 8, if we had handled what I suggested here ([Java 7 vs Java 8 HashMap resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430261/java-7-vs-java-8-hashmap-resizing)), then it'd at least been fail-safe.

May be better to answer both together but do we know why Java changed writeObject like this?

Again, I know HashMap is not thread-safe, but this change could result in

1. It will write the correct size, but write more number of key/value pairs (not in insertion order)
2. It will write the correct size, but write no elements
3. It will write the correct size, but not write any elements

2 & 3 will always result in de-serialization to fail

Comment: I can't seem to find  the implementation of `internalWriteEntries()`.

Comment: Added that @biziclop

Comment: I think it's the same reason as [khelwood commented on the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430261/java-7-vs-java-8-hashmap-resizing#comment75858783_44430261): Maybe someone thought, as long as we're not writing a thread-safe class, we shouldn't be going through the motions of thread-safety. --- And as I just commented there too: Why does it matter? Every implementation and every version can do it differently, as long as they adhere to the contract as defined by the javadoc. Nothing says that `writeObject` should be fail-fast, and no one should rely on fail-fast anyway.

Comment: I am not arguing there @Andreas.  All I am trying to do is to find a reasoning - if there is one.  The new implementation is worser (as it is neither fail-safe nor fail-fast) and resize change has made it less close Happens-Before.

Comment: It never had to be fail-safe, fail-fast, or Happens-Before, so when they re-coded it, those were never considerations. The new implementation is not *worse*, it is actually much better, because of the [new improved collision handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html).